# Retrieve text files in iOS app

Tags: ios, file, text, icloud, information-retrieval

I've been muddling through some iOS development, and I've hit a problem that Google hasn't helped me solve (yet).

What I'm trying to do is simply display text files in a UITextView.  The displaying is easy, it's the source of the text files that is more difficult.  What I'm planning on doing is writing a text file weekly and then having that text available in my app, I'm just not sure what the correct approach to storing and retrieving that text is.  Here is what I've thought about:

1)  Storing the text files within the app.  I don't like this because I'll have to provide application updates frequently or have a whole slew of text documents available for each update.

2)  iCloud.  I don't even know where to begin with this one...

I'm not looking for code samples unless someone has done something very similar to this previously.  I'm more looking for suggestions on how I might be able to store a text file (that I write from my laptop) and have that text file available to everyone who has my application installed.

Any thoughts?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is to store your text file somewhere that it will be publicly available. (try any file hosting service or maybe buy a basic hosting plan) To retrieve the data, all you need to do is call it with NSString's

```
+ (id)stringWithContentsOfURL:(NSURL *)url encoding:(NSStringEncoding)enc error:(NSError **)error
```

Be sure to provide the correct URL and I guess the encoding would be NSUTF8StringEncoding.

Comment: Note, this is a synchronous call and will block the thread you call it within until the data is fully downloaded.

Comment: Agreed, this should be wrapped in a method called on a background thread.

Comment: If I do this and display the contents of a stored string, I get all of the HTML code for the web page.  I'm assuming this has something to do with the fact that most file hosting services provide a URL for a download page, not a page with the actual text.  So instead of getting the contents of the text file, I get a whole bunch of HTML.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Is this stored is a web page? Isn't it just a simple txt file uploaded to a server? You're not supposed to receive any HTML junk when using this method.

Comment: If I use fileden, it works fine because it provides a direct link to the text file.  If I type in the url, it displays the text.  If I use some other hosting site (mediafire, etc.), they provide a download link, not the actual text.  Is there another way I should be doing it?